# Rspec passing view params to controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

My problem is I am trying to get as much coverage over my methods using rspec and I am unable to test a few certain lines. I am trying to pass a params hash to my controller method in my rspec to simulate the values from the view. Essentially, these values will filter results to be displayed on my index page.

The controller method I am testing is:

```
 def index
@buildings = Building.all

@buildings = @buildings.searchaddress(params[:searchaddress])


if params[:searchcompany] != nil
  @buildings = @buildings.searchcompany(params[:searchcompany][:management])
end

if params[:searchcompany] != nil
  @buildings = @buildings.searchcity(params[:searchcity][:city])
end

if params[:searchparking] == 'on'
  params[:searchparking] = 't'
  @buildings = @buildings.searchparking(params[:searchparking])
end

if params[:searchpets] != nil 
  params[:searchpets] = 't'
  @buildings = @buildings.searchpets(params[:searchpets])
end
```

end

I am trying to pass the params hash in my rspec test. I have tried a few ways including this one:

```
describe "viewing all buildings" do
    it "renders index template" do

        param = Hash.new()
        param[:searchcompany] = [management:'asdf']
        param[:searchcity] = [city:'asdf']    #have also tried {city:""}
        param[:searchparking] = ['on']
        param[:searchpets] = [true]
        param[:searchaddress] = ['lalala']

        get :index, params:param #{searchcompany:{management:'asdf'}, searchcity:{city:'asdf'}, searchparking:'on', searchpets:true}
        expect(response).to render_template('index')
        expect(assigns(:buildings)).to be_truthy


        expect(Building).to receive(Building.searchcompany)
        expect(Building).to receive(Building.searchcity)
        expect(Building).to receive(Building.searchpets)
        expect(Building).to receive(Building.searchparking)
    end
   end
```

The searchpets, searchcompany, etc. methods are from my Building model and are implemented as

```
def self.searchaddress(search)
where("address LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 1) BuildingsController viewing all buildings renders index template
 Failure/Error:
   def self.searchcity(search)
     where("city LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 # ./app/models/building.rb:39:in `searchcity'
 # ./spec/controllers/buildings_controller_spec.rb:103:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do i pass [:searchcity][:city] to my controller method through my rspec test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
 it "renders index template" do
    params = {
      searchcompany: {
        management: 'asdf'
      },
      searchcity: {
        city: 'asdf'
      },
      searchparking: 'on'
    }
    # All your expectations like 'expect(sth).to receive(:method)' go here
    get :index, params
    # Your remaining expectations go here
 end
```